# SSRS report design view disappeared in VSS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I have been using VSS 2012 to build SSRS reports for a year or two, and have suddenly lost the report design view.  This is the view that shows the "Design" and "Preview" panes.  If I open a report by rightclicking on it in the Solution Explorer, nothing appears to happen.  I can see the Report Data pane, but not the Design and Preview tabs.  I've searched Microsoft help pages for a shortcut key to display it, but have found nothing; there are shortcut keys for the Report Data pane, but not for the design view, as far as I can tell.

I suspect this is a newbie error of some kind, and I apologize in advance if so, but I've spent a good deal of time looking into the menus and MS help pages to no avail, so I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

After repeatedly opening and closing both the individual reports and solutions, I was able to fix this by closing the solution, then closing VSS completely, then re-opening it and re-opening the solution. It looks like it was a glitch; I suspect the view is not meant to ever not display. I hope this helps someone else.